# SQL Get First Non Null Value By Date From A Table

Tags: sql, join, case

Im trying a CASE expression, something like this:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_1 AS T1
ON T2.common_id = T1.common_id
CASE WHEN T1.column_1 IS NOT NULL
     THEN T1.column_1
     WHEN T1.column_1 IS NULL
     THEN get first value from T1.column that is not null by date
     ELSE 0
     END
```

Its the logic for that 6th line which I have written out what I want that I can't quite get right.

```
THEN get first value from T1.column that is not null by date
```

I have been looking at the FIRST_VALUE function but can't quite figure it out correctly. But there are maybe other ways to get it to work.

Comment: I would say you're on the right track with `FIRST_VALUE`. If you can add a table with sample data and expected output to your post we can assist you better.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? (Remove the unrelated tag.)

Comment: That's a `case` _expression_, not statement.

Comment: First_Value is a window function, I can't make out what your intention is from your code fragment, please add some suitable sample data etc and correct your contradictory RDBMS tags

Answer (score 0):

you can to find FIRST_VALUE that is not null with use this query

First use order by date for find date is null

after get value  FIRST_VALUE date with FIRST_VALUE

```
select *,FIRST_VALUE(date) over(partition by T1.common_id order by case when date is not null then 1 else 2 end)
from #table_2 T2
LEFT OUTER JOIN #table_1 AS T1
ON T2.common_id = T1.common_id
```

You can to insert the basic data with the following codes

```
create table #table_1 (id int,common_id int,date datetime)
create table #table_2 (id int,common_id int,name varchar(100))

insert into #table_1(id,common_id,date)
select 1,1,'2015-05-24' union select 2,1, null union select 3,1, '2014-09-01' union
select 4,4,null union select 5,4, '2019-08-05' union select 6,4, '2000-09-07' union
select 7,7,null union select 8,7, '2019-08-05'  union
select 9,12,'2019-08-06' union select 10,12, '2019-08-05'  union
select 11,18,'2019-08-06' union select 12,19, '2019-08-05'  



insert into #table_2(id,common_id,name)
select 1,1,'a' union select 2,1, null union select 3,1, 'b' union
select 4,4,'k' union select 5,4, 't' union select 6,4, 'c' union
select 7,7,'aaa' union select 8,7, 'sada'  union
select 9,12,'44dd' union select 9,12, '44'
```